# Catalyst template toolkit wrapper not works on Root controller

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

I'm set the wrapper on myapp::View::TT.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->config(
    TEMPLATE_EXTENSION => '.tt2',
    WRAPPER => 'wrapper.tt2',
    INCLUDE_PATH => [ha->path_to('root', 'src'),],
    render_die => 1,
    TIMER => 0,
);
```

and then create wrapper.tt2 with this content

```
[% IF no_wrapper; 
        debug("Passing $template.name  without any wrapper");
        content;
    ELSE;
        wrapper = wrapper || 'site_wrapper.tt2';
        debug("Applying $wrapper to $template.name");
        content WRAPPER $wrapper;
    END;
%]
```

Then, in Admin controller I wrote

```
sub begin :Private {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    $c->stash( wrapper => 'admin/admin_wrapper.tt2');
}
```

And that works fine.

But in Root Controller I can't set Wrapper and does't have wrapper.
I have wrapper site_wrapper.tt2, but I cant use it.

In Root controller I have

```
sub begin :Private {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    $c->stash( wrapper => 'site_wrapper.tt2');
}


    sub index :Path :Args(0) {
        my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

        # Hello World
        $c->response->body( "ok" );
    }
```

and thats output only "ok".
how can I use wrapper on Root?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting something into $c->response->body(), you override any template processing. I don't think there's anything intrinsically wrong with what you're doing as far as the `WRAPPER` directives are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out

```
    sub index :Path :Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->stash->{'template'}='some/whre/aTemplate.tt2';
    $c->stash->{'message'}="Hello world";
    $c->forward('View::TT') 
}
```

I think that  `$c->stash( wrapper => 'site_wrapper.tt2');` is not needed in the begin.
Every template that you will create, will include your wrapper once you configure the view.